# How to simulate noise in transient analysis of HSPICE?

Tags: hspice

How can I simulate the effect of different types of noise (thermal, flicker, jitter etc.) in transient analysis of HSPICE?
I want to make the sources noisy, make the FETs noisy.
The goal here is to make the simulation mimic the real-life scenario as much as possible.
How can I accomplish this in transient analysis?

I also want to add that I have come across a command '.trannoise'. Will this be sufficient for simulating all types of noise? Suggestions of resources explaining the parameters of the command will be highly appreciated. Explanations of the '.trannoise' command are quite scarce on the internet. The only documentation I have found till now is this snapshot:
[image: .trannoise syntax]

I am not clear how to use these parameters.

Comment: Chapter 30 of this document will answer your question: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee140/sp12/labs/hspice_sa.pdf